# How do we extract arrays from a nested numpy array based on conditions on the subarrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an output which is a nested numpy array. Each subarray has 10 float values, from this 'larger' array I want to extract those subarrays which have the maximum value at a specific index. 
Edit: (Edited for clarity)
Example of nested array -

```
[[1 0 0 0] [1 0 0 0] [0 0 1 0] [1 0 0 0] [0 1 0 0] [0 0.99 0 0]
```

Required output
`[[0 1 0 0] [0 0.99 0 0]]`  (We take the index as 1 in this example)

I want to extract those subarrays, whose value at the index 0,1,2 etc is the highest. So the condition here is extract all the subarrays where the value at index 1  (for eg) is the maximum.

Comment: I have edited it with a clearer example.

Comment: Usually we describe your array as multidimensional, in this case 2d with shape (6,4).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do it :

```
example = [[8, 5], [8,7], [5.6,1], [7, 9]]

# You choose which specific index you want tha max value
max_value_index= 0

# We use a list comprehension to select the corresponding rows
result = [x for x in example if x[max_value_index] == np.max(x)]
```

---

Output :

```
[[8, 5], [8, 7], [5.6, 1]
```

Comment: what does ```[column_i]``` do? does it correspond to the index value?

Comment: Thanks @AdityaDas, I had forgotten to rename it `max_value_index` like the others

Comment: This works, but it only works where the value is an integer. How do we make it work for float?

Comment: It also works with floats on my end. What inputs did you try ?

Comment: ```[[8, 5], [8,7], [5,6],[5.6,1]]```  the output should include ```[5.6,1]``` too right?

Comment: No it shouldn't since the max value of the index 0 is 8 and 5.6<8.

Comment: How do you decide which rows are included ? Isn't it based on the max value on a specific index ?

Comment: Ah, okay. I figured it out. The max value should be decided by the occurring values in that specific subarray, however your  code - what I think it does is scans all the specified indices and looks for only the maximum value in all the subarrays. In this case, 8.  I will edit the example in my post for more clarity

Comment: Ahhhhhhh I think I get it now @AdityaDas ! I edited my answer

Comment: np.max ! this was it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So from my understanding you have some `max_index` parameter, and you want to get all rows whose maximum element falls at that index.  To do this you can say "return all rows of my array for which the argmax of this row is equal to the max index", which in numpy is a one-liner:

```
arr = np.random.randn(100, 10)
max_index = 2
rows_with_max_at_max_index = arr[np.argmax(arr, axis=1) == max_index]  # A (N x 10) array
```